# RabbitMQ which exchange type should I use and When?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

We have 5 internal modules which are deployed to different servers on same internal network. for ex: SM,CS,MS,PA,CM. We want to use Rabbitmq as a MOM.

My questions are how to decide  :

1. how many topic exchange queues should I use ?(SM should commincate with multiple CM modules for 10 different operations) Should I create only one listener that listens all incoming messages and then redirects them to the related methods manually? Or should I create  queues for per operation, means 10 differents queue I need to create.
2. SM,CS and PA communicates with CM for different approachs.how should I decide how many of direct exchanges,topic exchanges,fanouts or headers exchanges shoud I use?

thanks

Comment: Please dont advice me to read rabbitmq General Routing Considerations, I already read it

Comment: exchanges are very lightweight entities inside RabbitMQ, queue are as well. Considering the numbers you are posting, there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: thanks for your answer,  I couldnt find any clear solution about relationship between performance and numbers of topics used .So I will design my system by applying routing considerations :
If you have a finite domain of routing keys in an application's graph then many fanout exchanges might be the right fit  (1:1 mapping of exchange per routing  key)
• If you have a potentially infinite number of routing keys, consider topic exchanges

Comment: Have you seen these series of blogposts?

http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/09/14/very-fast-and-scalable-topic-routing-part-1/

and

http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/03/28/very-fast-and-scalable-topic-routing-part-2/